# Java Scanner No Line Found, Not waiting for user input

Tags: java, loops, input, char

I am having an issue getting my Scanner object to read user input.  I want the scanner to read user input and save the input to a byte array.

If I use the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExamTaker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Variable Declaration
        char[] studentTest = new char[20];

        // Input Setup
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Take the test
        for (int i = 0; i < studentTest.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nAnswer " + (i+1) + " : ");
            studentTest[i] = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0); // The troubled line
        }
    }
}
```

I get the exception error as follows:

```
Answer 1 : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at ExamTaker.main(ExamTaker.java:14)
```

Having researched via Stack Overflow and Google, I have taken the suggestion to place my troubled line into a try-catch, as follows:

```
// Take the test
        for (int i = 0; i < studentTest.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nAnswer " + (i+1) + " : ");
            try {
                studentTest[i] = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Exception found");
            }
        }
```

However, this still won't produce the desired output for what I believe is an issue with the way I'm using the nextLine() method.  It merely throws the "Exception found" literal in front of each numbered answer.

I have also tried changing the for loop to a do-while loop, and tossing in a keyboard.getChar() in case it wasn't reaching the end of a line, but to no avail.

How do I get the user to input a string in which I take the first character and assign it to my char array in this instance?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**[Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)** throw `NoSuchElementException` whenno line was found, you should probablymake a call to **[Scanner#hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)**  before you invoke `nextLine()` to make sure that next line exists in the scanner.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < studentTest.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nAnswer " + (i+1) + " : ");
            if(keyboard.hasNextLine()){
                studentTest[i] = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0); // The troubled line
             }
        }
```

Also, i see that you just want to take the user input from the scanner, why not just use **[Scanner#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentTest.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nAnswer " + (i+1) + " : ");
            studentTest[i] = keyboard.next().charAt(0); // The troubled line
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Enclosing the troubled line in your suggested conditional avoids the exception being thrown, but does not allow for user input.  My assumption is that it isn't passing the conditional statement due to no such line already existing.  Also, using 'next()' gives me the same 'NoSuchElementException' as before.